# How do I check to see if an element of an array is occupied? +1 more

Tags: c, arrays

I have a `char*[]` array. I need to be able to assign strings to it and remove them again, but I don't know:

1. How to check to see if an element already has a string in it, so I don't overwrite it, and proceed to the next element if it is occupied already?
2. How  to free it off again afterwards?

If anyone needs more info then please let me know, I'm trying to use a `char *` array for the first time ever.

Answer (score 6):

Initialize each member of that array to NULL.
Then if some element contains NULL you can assume it is not initialized. e.g.

```
char *charPtr[3] = { NULL, NULL, NULL };
```

To assign a different string to some element, you can just reassign a new string to that element.

```
   charPtr[0] = "new string";
```

And as mentioned in comments, to remove a string you either do a

```
charPtr[0] = NULL;
```

or as below if and only if `charPtr[0]` contains a pointer obtained by `malloc` and family or function like `strdup`:

```
free(charPtr[0]); 
charPtr[0] = NULL;
```

Comment: ... and to remove a string : `charPtr[0] = NULL`; Or `free(charPtr[0]); charPtr[0] = NULL;` if and only if `charPtr[0]` contains a pointer obtained by a `malloc` like function or by `strdup`.